# Make array inside associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I've an array with keys below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Some ,name
            [codes] => 36101,36055,36071
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 31
            [name] => somename
            [codes] => 42049,42103,34003,42127,42095,36091,42113
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 27
            [name] => somename
            [codes] => 42107,36119,42009,36121,42087,42033,42083
        )
)
```

So, i'm trying to break array one more level at [codes] by "," tried exploding but not getting the result or may be i'm doing something wrong! can anyone help me on this ?!

TIA

Comment: I couldn't get your code to compile but in any case I'm pretty sure you would need to put that CSV list of numbers into another array.

Comment: The `codes` index,  is that a string of numbers?

Comment: @Kisaragi it was string of numbers wrapped in quotes which i removed and they are left with "," now which i need to explode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

Assume your array is like this

```
$arrayName = array(
    '0' => array(
        'id' => '1', 
        'name' => 'Some ,name', 
        'codes' => '36101,36055,36071', 
        ), 
    '1' => array(
        'id' => '2', 
        'name' => 'Some ,name', 
        'codes' => '42049,42103,34003,42127,42095,36091,42113', 
        ), 
    );
```

---

**Code**

```
foreach($arrayName as $key => $item)
{
    $newArray = explode(',', $item['codes']);
    $arrayName[$key]['codes'] = $newArray;

}
```

---

**Output will be**

[image]

Comment: it works! Thanks a Ton! such a small thing i must say but i can't get it to work,  thanks again.

Comment: @AnasAhmedKhanNiazi no problem. Happy to help. Enjoy coding :)